# Given axis-aligned rectangles in ${\mathbb R}^2$ with rational vertices, how to determine if there is an ellipse intersecting all rectangles?

Tags: geometry

This question originated from a computer programming situation but it seems I can't get a good answer to this question from that venue. Say we have a set $A$ of points in the plane, and then the points in $A$ are represented with finite base-2 precision using computer floating point, so that round-off error could explain each point being anywhere within a rectangle defined by the set of points whose limited precision representation gives the same coordinates. Thus, for each given floating point representative of a point in $A$, there is an explicitly known axis-aligned rectangle for where the corresponding true point in $A$ could be, as determined by the limited precision floating point representation. Naturally the vertices of each rectangle are rational, in fact, dyadic rationals.

So now the question. I would like to be able to determine whether it is POSSIBLE that round-off error defining the rectangles could explain the points in $A$ all lying on a common ellipse. Another way to say this is, given a set of axis-aligned rectangles, how do we determine if there exists an ellipse that intersects all the rectangles? An exact equation outputted for such an ellipse is not required.

I have a bad feeling that some sort of optimization or other kind of numerical methods will be required. If so, ideally I'd like the method to run fast. In practice we'll be dealing with just a handful (maybe 6 to 10) rectangles typically and the sizes of the rectangles will all be very small compared to the distances between different rectangles. But the number of problem instances will be large.

Comment: Just to make things more clear, you are basically given something like a mess of points each with associated rectangular "location tolerance" and want to know if an ellipse can intersect all of these location rectangles? I'm having a rasterized bitmap of an ellipse in my mind right now, where you are trying to check that it was in fact rasterized from an ellipse.

Comment: @AlexR Yes exactly, we have location tolerance which is rectangular and we want to know if we can find an ellipse passing "almost" through each point, up to the allowed tolerance in each point. I'd be very interested to hear your idea especially if you can formulate it in such a way to easily solve the problem. I think I see where you're getting at about "rasterized bitmap of an ellipse" but I don't know exactly how to make that an if-and-only-if condition for an ellipse to exist, compared to my situation constraints.

Comment: Seing you only have a few points, I'd try to select five separated as far as possible and see if they make up a conic section wich is "almost" an ellipse and also check if the remaining points are within tolerance of said ellipse. This means you need a way to 1. compute a conic section (fast) 2. check its ellipse-likeness (not sure but should also be fast) 3. compute the distance of a few points to a conic section (fast).

Comment: @AlexR Yeah that seems like a good plan, except I would have to be able to check if the implied tolerance for parameters of the ellipse (basically determined by round-off uncertainty in the points used to fit the ellipse) could possibly explain how all points could fit on the ellipse assuming they had round-off error. Maybe that's not as hard as it seems to me. I'll have to think more. Thank your for your comments.